# Function in Clojure that takes a list of n letters and returns a list

Tags: clojure

I need your help to write a function that takes a list of letters like ['a', 'b', 'c'] and returns another list of letters like ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], this is the first element is repeated only once the second element is repeated two times, the third element is repeated three times, etc. Thank you in advance!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(mapcat repeat (map inc (range)) ["a" "b" "c"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the final parameterized function is:

`(def expand
        (fn [letters]
          (mapcat repeat (map inc (range)) letters)) )`

Comment: @akond, i would say `(mapcat repeat (rest (range)) ["a" "b" "c"])` is a bit more readable